# Split a Twitter Bootstrap label

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, tags, label, padding

I'm using bootstrap's labels to show my blog's tags. What I would like to do is to "split" the label in two part:

1. first part with BG1 color contains the tag string
2. second part with BG2 color contains the tag count

This might not be easy and tricky because of all the padding that bootstrap define for each label.
 For example the trivial solution to change the background of the second part text will not work because it will be extended only to the length of the string not taking into account paddings. 
Below you can find a visual help of what I would like to accomplish.

[image: label]

So basically I need to work on the following span tag.

```
<li>
    <a class="label label-info" href="">
        <i class="icon-tag icon-white"></i> 
        another tag
        <span class="tagCountInfo">4</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: can you add any html and css of what you have got already

Comment: Done, for the CSS I haven't modified or added anything to the original bootstrap.css.

Comment: I've edited the code to be more specific.

Comment: are you able to change the html at all?

Comment: @Pete yes sure, I can change the html as I want, the code is just an example, not the final version.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<li>
    <a class="label label-info" href="">
        <i class="icon-tag icon-white"></i>
        tagName
        <span class="count">4</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

with

```
.count {
    background-color: #000000;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    margin-right: -4px;
    padding: 2px 4px 3px;
}
```

Beware: it's hacky...

Answer (score 1):

Regarding joining the two colored badges/labels, I found just using the existing bootstrap classes for badge and then just modifying the border radius on the matching corners works for me.

```
<span class="badge-container">
    <span class="badge-1">Another Tag</span>
    <span class="badge-2">4</span>
</span>
```

CSS (need font size 0 to remove gap between spans)

```
.badge-container {
    font-size: 0;
    .badge-1 {
        border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
    }
    .badge-2 {
        border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
    }
}
```